# How to release (remove) route from previous connection to public WIFI network using `nmcli` or `dhcpcd`?

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, dhcp

Once I connected to public network then after awhile (1-2 hours) it won't give me access to internet. I assume this is because my routing is configured with previous IP given by DHCP of the public router. How can I reconfigure my connection? Meaning how can I drop previous route and make it request new IP from the DHCP. But if I reboot it works (a captive screen is shown and then the internet).

```
[root@arch-pc art]# ip add
2: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether [IDHERE] brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.205.14/24 brd 192.168.205.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 43155sec preferred_lft 43155sec

[root@arch-pc art]# ip route
default via 192.168.205.254 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 20600 
192.168.205.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.205.14 metric 600 

[root@arch-pc art]# nmcli d disconnect wlp3s0
Device 'wlp3s0' successfully disconnected.
[root@arch-pc art]# nmcli d connect wlp3s0
Device 'wlp3s0' successfully activated with '40da5feb-1514-4b06-88bc-00491dadb1f3'.
[root@arch-pc art]# ip add
2: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether [IDHERE] brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.205.14/24 brd 192.168.205.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 43195sec preferred_lft 43195sec
[root@arch-pc art]# dhcpcd --rebind wlp3s0
sending commands to master dhcpcd process

[root@arch-pc art]# curl http://1.1.1.1 -v
*   Trying 1.1.1.1:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
^C
[root@arch-pc art]# ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
^C
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 21ms

[art@arch-pc ~]$ nmcli -version
nmcli tool, version 1.20.0-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
nmcli radio wifi off
```

and after a few seconds

```
nmcli radio wifi on
```

to see if that helps?

Comment: Thanks for a try! I didn't help. `nmcli` brings up the bad route whatever I did (`nmcli con del`, `ip route del...` and other). The only thing that helps is to reboot.